# html select(dropdownlist) added one extra line angularjs

Tags: c#, angularjs, select, controller

I am creating a web app in mvc-5 with the help of angularjs i created 10-12 pages and there are lots of insert/update/delete commands there and till now everything was working fine but today when i tried to update trainer name from `select`(html) one extra line is being added automatically

```
<select ng-model="mdupdpm" ng-options="a.empname as a.empname for a in gettrainername" ng-change="zoneupd(z)" style="width:270px;"></select>
```

and my angularjs controller

```
$scope.getupdateparams = function (param) {
            $('#update').modal({
                show: true,
                backdrop: 'static'
            });
            $scope.updtparam = param;
            console.log($scope.data.mdupm);
            $http.get('/companyregistration.asmx/updateempname', {
                params: {
                    empname: $scope.updtparam.pm
                }
            }).then(function (response) {
                $scope.gettrainername = response.data.info;
                console.log(response.data.info);
            })
        }
```

i don't know why this is not working because i did this in my previous pages and all of that worked well I am giving one example of worked code from my previous page

```
<select ng-model="ucomname" ng-options="o.comname as o.comname for o in comnamelistfun" ng-change="uucomname(o)" style="width:270px;"></select>
```

now my controller

```
$scope.updatefunction = function (param) {
                $scope.updateparam = param;
                //comnamebyid
                $scope.updmodal = true;
                $http.get('/csuv.asmx/getcompanyname', {
                    params: {
                        log: log,
                        pm: pm,
                        id: $scope.updateparam.Id
                    }
                })

                .then(function (response) {
                    {
                        $scope.updmodal = false;
                        $scope.comnamelistfun = response.data.cdetails;
                    }
                    $scope.ucomname = $scope.comnamelistfun[0].comname;

                });
```

what is wrong guys??

Comment: you mean an empty option?

Comment: If it's an empty option you need to specify a default selected item to not have an empty one